# JSON tabuler viewer or JSON in Table view

Tags: json

Actually, I have a large JSON array and I want to see it in table view and also want to edit it.

Please suggest me the best online editor for it.

Comment: Do you want's to do it online? 

You can try it: http://json2table.com/# it will shows your json as table view.

Regards,

Comment: thanks, but I can not edit the values in table

Answer (score 0):

https://jsontotable.fonlow.org/ is a PWA which can be used offline, once ever loaded or installed.
If you want to edit nodes in a table view, https://jsoneditoronline.org/ looks like a good one which is also PWA. However, this site is with many banner advertisements that generate a lot HTTP traffics. Mind the risks.